# Managing cached files in browser

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, caching, aiohttp

I want to manage when my static file has been cached in browser or downloaded as a new due to file timestamp.

So if the change time of source file (js, css, png ....) is higher than browser cached file time flag, script will send response 200 (download the file) else  304 (nothing changed - use cached file)

So I have edited my aiohttp script like this:

```
import pytz
@partial(app.router.add_route, 'GET', '/static/{journey:.*}')
async def handle(request):
    fullpath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static/'+request.match_info['journey'])
    response = web.Response(headers={'Content-Disposition': 'Attachment','filename': fullpath.split('/')[-1]})
    time = request.if_modified_since
    status = 200
    #get file
    try:
        timestamp = os.path.getmtime(fullpath)
        timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp).replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
    except OSError as e:
        print(e)
        status = 404
        timestamp = False

    if time is None or timestamp is None:
        response.last_modified = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
    else:
        if timestamp and timestamp < time:
            status = 304

    if status == 200:
        t = fullpath.split('.')[-1]
        if t in ['png', 'jpg', 'gif']:
            response.content_type = 'image/{}'.format(t)
        elif t == 'js':
            response.content_type = 'application/javascript'
        async with aiofiles.open(fullpath, mode='rb') as f:
            response.body = await f.read()

    response.set_status(status)
    return response
```

and also removed

```
app.router.add_static('/static', 'static')
```

Everything works fine but i thing the part of the code where file content is set has not so good solution because of reading.

```
async with aiofiles.open(fullpath, mode='rb') as f:
    response.body = await f.read()
```

Has anyone another idea how i can deal with this problem in aiohttp ?
Thank you Michal

Comment: What is the problem with reading file there?